# Can't Pass `std::array` From Within Closure

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Using the following declarations:

```cpp
#include <array>

template <typename V> void makeError(V& v) {}
```

the following code snippet fails to compile under MSVC 16.11.13 with `/std:c++17`:

```cpp
int main() {
    [&]() {
        std::array bugs{0};
        [&]() { makeError(bugs); };
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is as follows: `main.cpp(9,5): error C2955: 'std::array': use of class template requires template argument list`

The same code compiles perfectly fine under GCC 10.4 with `--std=c++17`. The real problem came up when I tried removing the inner closure:

```cpp
int main() {
    [&]() {
        std::array bugs{0};
        makeError(bugs);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Or the outer closure:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::array bugs{0};
    [&]() { makeError(bugs); };
    return 0;
}
```

Both of these compile happily under MSVC and GCC.

Is the first snippet invalid C++? If so, what part of the standard am I violating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in msvc's legacy lambda processor. Your code compiles if you pass [`/Zc:lambda`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-lambda?view=msvc-170): https://godbolt.org/z/91z4chhTx

This seems to be the matching bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/class-template-argument-deduction-fails-in-the-bod-1/414204

##### How I found this

I would always recommend using godbolt in cases like this, since it allows you to quickly switch between compilers, versions and command line args.

If something smells like a compiler bug, checking the latest versions is always a good idea. If something compiles under gcc & clang, but not msvc, it smells like a compiler bug.

I tried your code in the latest msvc and since it involves lambdas and captures, I remembered that there were changes to that in c++20, so I tried compiling as such. Since that worked, I had look through cppreference to see if I could find any relevant change to the standard that might legitimately cause this. I didn't find any, but then remembered that msvc has also constantly be increasing its standards conformance over the recent years.

So I used [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170) with c++17 and once I noticed that this builds, I had a look through [the conformance flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-conformance?view=msvc-170) and found `/Zc:lambda`.

This confirmed this as a fixed compiler bug to me. And fixed bugs often have bug reports, so I googled the keywords that seemed relevant to the situation:
[msvc nested lambdas template deduction](https://www.google.cm/search?q=msvc+nested+lambdas+template+deduction&hl=en&biw=1505&bih=1136&ei=LXdYY-SWNo3zkgWI0LyIDw&ved=0ahUKEwik4Z-Eyvz6AhWNuaQKHQgoD_EQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=msvc+nested+lambdas+template+deduction&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzoFCAAQkQI6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAWEB46BwghEKABEApKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQTFjHOmDfO2gBcAF4AIABcYgBjxmSAQQyNy44mAEAoAEByAEDwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz). The bug report is the second result for me.

Comment: I'm curious how you found this in case I run into something similar in the future. What was your process?

Comment: Good question. Added that to my answer.